# java mysql connection across network

Tags: java, mysql, networking, phpmyadmin, database-connection

I need to connect to a mysql database across a network.
The connection string ive given is

```
"jdbc:mysql://host/dbname"
```

i can access the site across the network but the only problem is with the java database connection.
Ive updated the phpmyadmin.conf file giving

```
# Deny from all
 Allow from all
```

But still the database connection cannot be made.
Please help me..

Comment: Do you setup user and password in your connection?

Comment: ive setup a user with no password.. i hope thats ok. The host option for the user is given as 'any host'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much aboud phpmyadmin, but what I did to configure a remote db:

1. The connection string is: jdbc:mysql://host:port/dbname

   - The port is 3306 by default
2. The mysql user is often name@localhost, you need to configure a user for the remote (client) machine (IP address, hostname, wildcard)

HTH

Comment: ive configured a user ('client') for it for all hosts. so the username should be 'client@localhost' right?

Comment: If the username is `client@localhost` then only users from the same machine as the DB is running on can login. You need something like `client@%` or `client@my_host_name` ( for one specific client PC). [Mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-users.html) may help

Comment: ive tried client@%, but now its giving the error- cant get find hostname for your address"

Comment: ive added " [mysqld]

skip-name-resolve "

to my "my.ini" file and it was solved

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there are few things you need to check ...

1) If your database got username/password

2) Have you restarted your server after altering `phpmyadmin.conf`?

3) Make sure you are connecting to the correct port. Ex: mysql://host:port/dbname (if port differs from default.

4) make sure that the PC that have the DB allows incoming connections through the port.

If you still facing problems, try disabling your antivirus/firewall on the PC that have the DM and try.

Comment: ive used a username without password. i hope thats ok. have done all the rest

Comment: it doesn`t matter if you just use an account with only username, as the default account for MySQL is "root" without a password.

Comment: And I see that you stated that you have done all the rest, still facing the same?